# Snap.svg capturing mousewheel events

Tags: events, mousewheel, snap.svg

I would like to take the **mousewheel** event on an element, but have't found anything on the documentation. Do you have an example of the kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of any direct Snap methods to use mousewheel, but I guess you can just add a mousewheel listener...this example works in Chrome, you may need to tweak and add test case for different browsers.

```
var s = Snap(400, 620);
var c = s.circle(30,30,30);

if( (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {
    s.node.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
} else {
    s.node.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
}

function mouseWheelHandler (ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log( ev.target.localName );
}
```

Edit: Have updated to check for firefox as well.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZUh3/3/)

Comment: "**.node**", I understand. In this case I could use jQuery for event. Thank you very much.